# WaitGroup with Channels

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, channel

I've been playing around with [this](https://medium.com/rungo/anatomy-of-channels-in-go-concurrency-in-go-1ec336086adb) and came up with:

```
type Function struct{
    Function func(*TaskGroup, []interface{})
    Args []interface{}
}

type TaskGroup struct{
    Group sync.WaitGroup
    Functions []Function
}

func (x *TaskGroup) Start() {
    for _, Function := range x.Functions{
        x.Group.Add(1)
        go Function.Function(x, Function.Args)
    }
    x.Group.Wait()
}
```

In order to work easier with mutliple functions I have to wait for.

The following tests will work and I do not understand why:

```
func auxC(x *TaskGroup, args []interface{}){
    defer x.Group.Done()
    messageOut := args[0].(chan string)
    messageOut <- "TestC"
}
func auxD(x *TaskGroup, args []interface{}){
    defer x.Group.Done()
    messageOut := args[0].(chan string)
    messageOut <- "TestD"
}

func TestTaskGroupBaseB(t *testing.T) {
    messageC := make(chan string, 1)
    messageD := make(chan string, 1)

    tg := TaskGroup{
        Functions: []Function{
            {auxC, []interface{}{messageC}},
            {auxD, []interface{}{messageD}},
        },
    }
    tg.Start()

    fmt.Println(<- messageC)
    fmt.Println(<- messageD)

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

I first tried with unbuffered channels like this:

```
messageC := make(chan string)
messageD := make(chan string)
```

But it doesn't work it just gets stuck forever without doing anything, **so i have a few questions:**

1. Why do buffered channels with size 1 work while unbuffered doesn't?
2. Isn't unbuffered by default size 1?

**Refactored code, see comments:**

Main/Tests:

```
func auxC(args []interface{}){
    messageOut := args[0].(chan string)
    messageOut <- "TestC"
}
func auxD(args []interface{}){
    messageOut := args[0].(chan string)
    messageOut <- "TestD"
}

func TestTaskGroupBaseB(t *testing.T) {
    messageC := make(chan string,1)
    messageD := make(chan string,1)

    tg := TaskGroup{
        Functions: []Function{
            {auxC, []interface{}{messageC}},
            {auxD, []interface{}{messageD}},
        },
    }
    tg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(<- messageC)
    fmt.Println(<- messageD)

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Task Group:

```
type Function struct{
    Function func([]interface{})
    Args []interface{}
}

type TaskGroup struct{
    Group sync.WaitGroup
    Functions []Function
}

func (x *TaskGroup) Wait() {
    for _, function := range x.Functions{
        x.Group.Add(1)
        go func(x *TaskGroup, f Function){
            defer x.Group.Done()
            f.Function(f.Args)
        }(x, function)
    }
    x.Group.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Why would "ubuffered" mean "a buffer of size 1"?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html

Comment: @jcfollower nop, will do it, looks very good, thanks :)

Comment: Side note: `Start` is a not-very-good name for this `TaskGroup` executor, because it not only starts all the functions, it then waits for all of them to signal that they're done. So it is a `Do`, not a `Start`.

Comment: Design note: The `WaitGroup` argument `x` is passed to the called functions only so that they can call `Done` on it. (They will do nothing else with this `WaitGroup`.) So it makes more sense to eliminate it as an argument to the functions that `TaskGroup` calls. Have `TaskGroup` spin off each function via an anonymous goroutine that (1) calls the function, then (2) calls `Done` on the waitgroup. Then you don't need to make the functions take `x *TaskGroup` as a receiver at all.

Comment: (Both of these are just asides; JimB and Burak Serdar have already answered the channel question.)

Comment: thank you @torek, just beautiful, see the refactor :)

Comment: In the updated code, either just call `x.Group.Done()` directly, or move the `defer` above the call to `f.Function`—the only reason to use a `defer` here is to make sure it runs even if the function-or-call-thereof itself panics (and some outer system uses recover). To make that work, you must defer the `Done` call before calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a channel with buffer size 1, first write buffers data, then goroutines end and you can read the buffered data in the main goroutine.

When channel size is zero a write to the channel blocks until another goroutine reads from it. So both of your goroutines are waiting to write the channels. If you move the Wait() call after the channel reads in main it should work.